# Multiple select radio button with Jquery Ui Tabs and Malsup Cycle slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

When i press one of my radio button i want every other radio button in each `<form>` with the same value to change aswell.
I cant get this to work, ive made a js fiddle for you to check http://jsfiddle.net/Wpw9u/2/

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to my problem now:

```
I just had to change .prop("selected", true) to .prop("checked", true);
```